# Complex SQL ranking query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have 3 fairly simple tables:

users

```
user_id
1
2
3
```

radio_songs

```
song_id  song
1        SomeName
2        OtherName
```

radio_rates

```
user_id  song_id  rate (from 1 to 5)
1        1        5
2        1        4
1        2        2
2        2        2
```

I've wrote quite complex query targetting MySQL that calculates current "position" (rank) of the song according to **[lower bound of Wilson score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html)**.

```
SELECT rank FROM(
    SELECT x.song AS song, x.ci_lower_bound AS ci_lower_bound, (@row:= @row + 1) AS rank FROM(
        SELECT song, ((SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + 1.9208) / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25)) - 1.96 * SQRT((SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) * SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25)) / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25)) + 0.9604) / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25))) / (1 + 3.8416 / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25))) AS ci_lower_bound
        FROM radio_rates
        INNER JOIN radio_songs ON radio_rates.song_id = radio_songs.song_id 
        GROUP BY radio_rates.song_id
        ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC
    ) x, (SELECT @row := 0) r
) xx WHERE xx.song = @song
```

This query basically accepts `@song` parameter and:

- Calculates lower bound of Wilson score and orders by it in descending order
- Adds row number to each row, as I didn't find any way for `ROW_NUMBER()` in MySQL
- And finally gets rank of the song we're looking for

The query works properly and I'm quite satisfied with it, but when we have multiple songs with the same score then due to sorting the resulting rank can vary between executions of the same SQL query. I wanted to avoid that by getting `MIN()` rank from all songs that have the same score as the target one, but the query got so complicated that I'm struggling how to do that without a temporary table - is it even possible?

I'd appreciate help, as well as any recommendations in terms of performance/optimization of above query.

I know that it'd be worth it to consider simply adding another score column to songs table and calculating it on each insert/update via trigger, but I'd want to avoid that if possible and calculate rank on-demand. Therefore SQL query itself is most important for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `RANK()` is a pain to implement in MySQL.  `DENSE_RANK()` is a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT rank FROM(
    SELECT x.song AS song,
           (@row:= @row + 1) AS rn,
           IF(@last_score = x.ci_lower_bound, @rank, @rank := @row) AS rank
           (@last_score := x.ci_lower_bound) AS ci_lower_bound
    FROM(
        SELECT song, ((SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + 1.9208) / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25)) - 1.96 * SQRT((SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) * SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25)) / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25)) + 0.9604) / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25))) / (1 + 3.8416 / (SUM((rate - 1) * 0.25) + SUM((5 - rate) * 0.25))) AS ci_lower_bound
        FROM radio_rates
        INNER JOIN radio_songs ON radio_rates.song_id = radio_songs.song_id 
        GROUP BY radio_rates.song_id
        ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC
    ) x, (SELECT @row := 0, @rank := null, @last_score := null) r
) xx WHERE xx.song = @song
```

The changes are:

```
SELECT x.song AS song,
       (@row:= @row + 1) AS rn,
       IF(@last_score = x.ci_lower_bound, @rank, @rank := @row) AS rank
       (@last_score := x.ci_lower_bound) AS ci_lower_bound
```

and

```
(SELECT @row := 0, @rank := null, @last_score := null) r
```

In this line

```
IF(@last_score = x.ci_lower_bound, @rank, @rank := @row) AS rank
```

You set the rank to the row number only if the score has changed compared to the last row. If the score is the same, the rank from the last row is used.

**Warning:** Using session variables this way, you are always at risk that your code will return unexpected results when you upgrade to a new version. If it works, then it is because of how the engine is implemented. There is no guarantee, that the expressions will be executed in the expected order.

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> ```
> SET @a = @a + 1;
> ```
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined.

[User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: I know, I hate myself for starting with user-defined variables in select, but there is no other way to get row number functionality in MySQL - it's already available as window function in MariaDB 10.2, so I expect to move to it soon and get rid of it in the first place.

Of course your solution works, for which I'm very grateful. I just had to cast rank to int as my server returned it as a blob. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: You can get row numbers without user-defined variables using a temporary table with an AUTO_INCEREMNT column. But to get the rank as you need is a bit more comlicated. You would then just need to select the `min(row_number)` with the same score.

Comment: @JustArchi try to change `@rank := null` to `@rank := 0` - Then you might not need to cast the `rank`.